# It is possible to use Tailwind CSS to style Chakra UI components?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, chakra-ui

It is possible to use Tailwind CSS to style Chakra UI components?

Answer (score 18):

[Response](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/634#issuecomment-619626792) from the creator of Chakra UI:

> [...] yes you can definitely use Chakra with Tailwind since it's just a bunch of class names you need to add.
>
> Yes, Chakra's theme is inspired by Tailwind so you should be pretty good and most of Chakra's styling props should feel relatable.
>
> Give it a try and let me know what you think.

Comment: The above link also has an example of how to resolve differences in the color themes of the two libraries. Specifically, mbrookson shows how to override Chakra's color theme, so it uses Tailwind's color theme. *----(how annoying, I cannot get a direct link to mbrookson's post - github's "share link" won't copy the post URL to my phone's clipboard!! And github doesn't show the URL anywhere. [In contrast, SO share link is perfect: it does both!]. The only access to the post's url is if "share link" actually copies it to your clipboard. Not an issue for that short thread, but it is in general!)*

Comment: @SherylHohman here's the link to mbrookson's comment that describes the way to do it. https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/634#issuecomment-660548480